# Organizing the post array

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Here is my form

```
 <form name="input" action="http://localhost/shopper/index.php?route=module/cart/insert_shopper" method="post">
<input quantity="4" type="hidden" name="28" value="1">
<input type="hidden" quantity="3" name="29" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I have this format

```
  [post] => Array
    (
        [28] => 1
        [29] => 1
    )
```

I really want the post array to be products and then a list on product ids with quantities ...is there an easy way to change the form

so on the next page i can do this

```
$products = $_POST['products']
foreach( $products as $p)
{
if( isset($p) && $p<>'')
{
///// place your code here
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="hidden"  name="products[29][3]" value="1">


$products = $_POST['products']
foreach( $products as $product_id=>$quantity)
{
echo $product_id;
echo $quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML form you can add array brackets after the end of the name attribute value, eg:

```
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'products[]' value = '12'/>
    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'qty12' value = '16'/>
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'products[]' value = '13'/>
    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'qty13' value = '72'/>
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'products[]' value = '14'/>
    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'qty14' value = '1'/>
```

The PHP in the receiving script will then treat `$_POST['products']` as an array.  The quantity can be seen by:

```
foreach($_POST['products'] as $k => $v) {
    echo($_POST['qty'.$v] . "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="input" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="29" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="28" value="4">
    <input type="hidden" name="27" value="2">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

<?php

if (!empty($_POST))
{
    foreach ($_POST as $id => $quantity)
    {
        echo 'ID: '.$id.' quantity: '.$quantity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="28" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="29" value="3">
```

Will give you

```
[post] => Array
    (
        [28] => 4
        [29] => 3
    )
```